# How to remove left sidebar in Metronic Admin Theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css, metronic

I'm using Metronic admin theme. I have a login screen with footer, header and sidebar. I want to remove sidebar completely on my login page.

I researched solutions but none of the solutions solved my problem. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without your code, I'm assuming you just need to delete the page-sidebar-fixed class from your body element. Provide more code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the HTML template after every update because there might be few changes which are not listed in Changelog (I also have few problems from time to time). This is probably the only solution, just copy the template and edit it for your needs.

From default, the login page doesn't show header or sidebar, so the problem will be on your side. See the latest Login Page https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/demo1/custom/pages/user/login-1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the sidebar bu using the LayoutConfig.js file. In the file, you can find this object:
**Replace:**

```
        self: {
            skin: 'dark',
            display: true,
            fixed: true,
            minimize: {
                toggle: true,
                default: false
            }
        },
```

**TO:**

```
aside: {
        self: {
            skin: 'dark',
            display: false,
            fixed: true,
            minimize: {
                toggle: true,
                default: false
            }
        },
```

Or you can change **display** value through redux

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove all between this tag:

```
<!--begin::Aside-->
...
...
...
<!--end::Aside-->
```